# Embedded File Extractor For PyPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

About a week ago I had asked for a tool (other than pdftk) which could extract the embedded files in a PDF (in linux). It seems there was nothing great available. Since I was coding in Python, I built a pure-python implemention for this in PyPDF. So now I have a function in PyPDF that can do this. Can someone tell me how I can suggest this code for addition to the PyPDF library?

Comment: Is this PyPDF or PyPDF2? If it is PyPDF2, you should fork from https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2, make changes and make a pull request there. In fact, I am looking for something like this as well, and currently using pdftk. But if your code is available, it would be great :)

Comment: I've built on top of PyPDF. Sorry I hadn't looked at this for a while. If you still need the code, I could share it some place. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using another approach: save an URL in the PDF's metadata and download the file from remote server.

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple files within a PDF:

- Images: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-images.html
- Annotations - https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/reading-pdf-annotations.html - especially FileAttachments
- Attachments - https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/pull/1611 (will be added on Sunday)

I've linked to the public documentation for hints how to extract that.